# Multiple y-axis with different sizes

Tags: reactjs, echarts

With Apache ECharts, is it possible to change the size of an y-axis, like on the screenshot below?
I was checking the API but couldn't find a way to do this.

[image: charts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echarts has option Grid (https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#grid). It's the same as layer. You can make multiple grids and attach each axis to each grid. Next you should define grid coordinates on canvas and set height (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-series-layout-by)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to achieve it using the grid system. This other example was also quite helpful to understand how to position multiple charts: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-anscombe-quartet